# TO Clean C# program cache memory

Tags: c#, caching, memory

I want to set automatically cleaning method for a desktop running application, because it throw an error "out of memory".

Is there any way to do this?

.

Comment: This question does not contain enough data to help you but you can unassign big variables and call `GC.Collect`

Comment: If you're running out of memory with a C# then it's because you're not releasing some resource, or you just require more resource than is available.  The garbage collector will run when it is ready to run, as determined by its own internal logic.  Triggering garbage collections yourself can have a severe and unintended performance impact as items are promoted to longer serving heaps.

Answer (score 4):

There is already an "automatic cleaning method"; the GC. You should virtually never need to tell it what to do - it understands memory more than most people do. If your code is throwing OOM, you need to investigate *why*; for example, are you leaking objects? (static event handlers are notorious for this); are you asking for huge slabs of contiguous memory (huge arrays, etc)? are  you asking for an array that  is more than 2 GiB (without  large array support enabled)? are you running on 32-bit and just  using lots of memory? is it actually not really an OOM condition, but really GDI+ handle exhaustion (which demonstrates in the same way)?

The first thing  to check is how much memory your process is using - and how much free memory the OS has - when it throws OOM. If there is plenty of free memory, it isn't actually OOM (unless you're using over 1 GiB on a 32-bit system, in which case all bets are off).